# php read from array inside class

Tags: php, json, class

when i use print_r for the response from API URL i got the following result:

```
stdClass Object(
[Messages] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [MessageID] => 990950058
                [Recipient] => 966000000000
                [Status] => Queued
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [MessageID] => 990950059
                [Recipient] => 966500000000
                [Status] => Queued
            )

    )

[NumberOfUnits] => 1
[Cost] => 0.00000
[Balance] => 2.89050
[TimeCreated] => 2016-11-10 14:03:49
[CurrencyCode] => SAR
```

)

the problem is i want to make a loop to  read the values for **MessageID**
how i can do it?

Comment: foreach($result->Messages as $message){
$message->MessageID
}

Comment: `foreach($whateverYourPrintRd->Messages as $message) { echo $message->MessageId; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so simple use `foreach` is used to loop through each key/value pair

```
foreach($your_variable->Messages as $row) 
 { 
   echo $row->MessageID; 
 }
```

Comment: trying to do it but i got this error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: $your_variable mean your variable name . make sure that

Comment: foreach($response->Messages as $row) 
 { 
   echo $row->MessageId; 
 } 
the variable name is $response

Comment: small typo error in MessageId is d sholud be capse letter like this MessageID